# How to Defer Ember views from synchronously updating from bound input fields

Tags: ember.js

Let's say I have a group of editable users, when one goes to edit that user, ember will synchronously update all views as you type into the bound input text field.

This is cool and all but from an UX point of view it can be misleading.. those values hadn't changed on the server at all.. What I'd like to do is to defer the view update until I set it in the corresponding action method based on a success message from the server.

I have found that when I use `{{bind-attr value=firstName}}` instead of `{{input value=firstName}}` that indeed ember no longer updates the view on changing the input field, however the newly typed value is no longer accessible in the actions submit method via this.get('firstName')?

**Example.hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="user">
<h3>Edit {{fullName}}</h3>
<p>
<label>First Name</label>
{{input value=firstName}}
</p>

<p>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input {{bind-attr value=lastName}} />
</p>

<p>
<button {{action 'submit'}}>Submit</button>
</p>
</script>
```

**Example Controller**

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    submit: function(){
      // call to server, on confirmation set 'Globally' first and last names 
      console.log(this.get('firstName') + " - " + this.get('lastName'));
    }
  }
});
```

Here's my jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/jipik/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a secondary set of variables.  Add to your controller a variable named `firstNameEdited` and set its value initially to `firstName`.  Value bind your input field to this new value and submit this new value to your api call.  On a successful return of the API call, update `firstName` with the value of `firstNameEdited`.